How can I assign a shortcut to close other tab in Firefox
I find myself closing other tabs in Firefox. Is there a way to assign a shortcut for this action, thereby circumventing the necessity of using my mouse?
enter image description hereRepeatedly,

Much depends on where you are trying to close a tab from
These are the common keyboard shortcuts as they relate to Windows and Tabs which are preset in Firefox without general need for further action from the user:

So, in your context if you are not on the tab you wish to close cycle through the tabs in recently used order - needs setting in settings see reference - and when you land on the tab you wish to close hit Ctrl W or Ctrl F4.
You can see the full list of keyboard shortcuts from Mozilla here
